# Cache dependencies in GitHub Actions on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, caching, github-actions

I am having a Github action which runs on Windows OS. Then, for caching the dependencies, I use the `actions/cache@v2`. But, it is not working as expected. When I saw the debug logs, the size of the cache is only about `30 B`.
[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
name: Build
on: push

jobs:
 build_on_win:
runs-on: windows-latest
if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'skip-publish')"

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - uses: actions/setup-node@master
    with:
      node-version: 15
  - name: Cache NPM dependencies
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: ~/.npm
      key: ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-
  - name: install dependencies
    run: npm install

  rest of the code..
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching package dependencies is a feature that is already available in the [actions/setup-node@v2](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-node-js-environment). You don't have to configure *actions/cache@v2* and instead of that what you can do is use the *setup-node@v2* action like below and you just have to add `cache: 'npm'` and it will automatically detect and will cache the dependencies.

```yaml
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: '14'
    cache: 'npm'
- run: npm install
- run: npm test
```

If you have monorepo then you can also define the path

```yaml
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: '14'
    cache: 'npm'
    cache-dependency-path: subdir/package-lock.json
- run: npm install
- run: npm test
```

You can read more about it in [Caching packages dependencies](https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-packages-dependencies).

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Btw it takes about `1 minute and 90 seconds`  to install dependencies

Comment: Yes it takes time to install the dependencies but if you want to decrease the installation time you can do `npm ci` instead of `npm install`, also make sure that you have `package-lock.json` inside the respository.

Comment: Ooh! Thank you! Let me try it!

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm... taking only about `53 s` now

Comment: Hi @HamzaAnis, based on the GitHub docs, [`setup-node` does not cache the `node_modules`](https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-global-packages-data)